# MySQL Converting Database Column From Blob to separate pieces

Tags: mysql, sql, database, migration

I am trying to take a blob out of an old MySQL table and make a new table for it, in an effort to reach first normal form.  However, to covert the data already in the database from blob into multiple rows in the new table is turning out to be no easy feat.

What is the easiest way to achieve the conversion with SQL command?

Parent Table:

```
CREATE  TABLE TEST.People (
  `id` INT  AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `age` INT,
  `height` INT,
  `weight` INT  ,
  `variations` BLOB DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
);
```

New Table:

```
CREATE  TABLE TEST.Variations (
  `id` INT  AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `chr` INT,
  `start` INT,
  `stop` INT  ,
  `type` ENUM('SNP','INDEL','CNV') DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
);
```

When I run SELECT id,variations FROM TEST.People;
I get:

```
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | variations                                                                                                           |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  3 | xp   t !3:124093754-124467278/CNVt 7:78030601-79638023/CNV                                                           |
|  6 | xp                                                                                                                   |
|  9 | xp                                                                                                                   |
| 12 | xp   t !1:84289718-85466763/CNV                                                                                      |
| 15 | xp                                                                                                                   |
| 18 | xp                                                                                                                   |
| 21 | xp                                                                                                                   |
| 24 | xp                                                                                                                   |
| 27 | xp                                                                                                                   |
| 30 | xp   t !10:166909544-166909544/SNPt !2:66903445-66903445/SNPt !2:166897864-166897864/CNVt !7:6892788-6892788/SNP     |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So what I want the TEST.Variations table to have after conversion is this:

```
+----+-----+-----------+-----------+----------+
| id | chr | start     | stop      | type     |  
+----+-----+-----------+-----------+----------+
|  3 |   3 | 124093754 | 124467278 | CNV      |
|  3 |   7 |  78030601 |  79638023 | CNV      |
| 12 |   1 |  84289718 |  85466763 | CNV      |
| 30 |  10 | 166909544 | 166909544 | SNP      |
| 30 |   2 |  66903445 |  66903445 | SNP      |
| 30 |   2 | 166897864 | 166897864 | CNV      |
| 30 |   7 |   6892788 |   6892788 | SNP      |
+----+-----+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: this will have to be done with some type of regexp most likely. Question: does `t ` always come before your strings that need chopped into the separate columns when the strings repeat in the current blob? and does the `!` have anything to do with the migration or should it be ignored as in the example?

Comment: This is going to be off-the-charts difficult to do and to test in pure MySQL query language; the right tool for parsing your `variations` blob column is a string-processing language like PHP or PERL.

Comment: @amaster507 - at the present time MySQL does not implement `REGEX_REPLACE` - like functionality.

Comment: I did not say it did... as OllieJones stated, you will need another language to make this update and use a regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all** two things:

1. You have an inconsistency in data for id 3.There is no `!` right before `7:...`. I hope that is just a typo

   ```
   xp   t !3:124093754-124467278/CNVt 7:78030601-79638023/CNV
                                     ^^
   ```
2. If you want to have an `auto_increment` column in your target table then you schema should look something like this

   ```
   CREATE  TABLE variations 
   (
     `var_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `id`    INT, -- id from People goes here and it's not UNIQUE
     `chr`   INT,
     `start` INT,
     `stop`  INT ,
     `type`  ENUM('SNP','INDEL','CNV') DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`var_id`) 
   );
   ```

**Now** you can transfer data from `People` to `Variations` table with a query

```
INSERT INTO variations (id, chr, start, stop, type)
SELECT id, 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(variation, ':', 1) chr,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(variation, '-', 1), ':', -1) start,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(variation, '-', -1), '/', 1) stop,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(variation, '/', -1) type
  FROM
(
  SELECT p.id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.variations, 't !', n.n), 't !', -1) variation
    FROM 
  (
    SELECT id, SUBSTR(variations, 9) variations
      FROM people 
     WHERE variations LIKE 'xp   t !%'
  ) p CROSS JOIN 
  (
     SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
       FROM 
      (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
     ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
      ORDER BY n
  ) n
   WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(p.variations) - LENGTH(REPLACE(p.variations, 't !', ''))) / 3
   ORDER BY id
) q
 ORDER BY id, chr, start, stop, type;
```

***Note:**  this query will split **up to 100 variations per id**. If you need more or less you can adjust a limit by editing the inner subquery with `n` alias, which produces number (tally) table on the fly.*

Result:

```
| VAR_ID | ID | CHR |     START |      STOP | TYPE |
|--------|----|-----|-----------|-----------|------|
|      1 |  3 |   3 | 124093754 | 124467278 |  CNV |
|      2 |  3 |   7 |  78030601 |  79638023 |  CNV |
|      3 | 12 |   1 |  84289718 |  85466763 |  CNV |
|      4 | 30 |  10 | 166909544 | 166909544 |  SNP |
|      5 | 30 |   2 | 166897864 | 166897864 |  CNV |
|      6 | 30 |   2 |  66903445 |  66903445 |  SNP |
|      7 | 30 |   7 |   6892788 |   6892788 |  SNP |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32763/1)** demo